# How to convert Array formula of excel file to equivalent regular/normal formula in excel?

Tags: excel, formula

Hi I have a array formula in which i need to press CSE`(ctrl+shift+enter)` to make it work.
And more importantly i want to evaluate this formula in java by `apache` poi API,which is not supported till the date.

Is anyone can help me regarding this,will be really appreciated.

```
{=INDEX('02_BillList'!$B$1:$W$4000,MATCH(1,('02_BillList'!$B$1:$B$4000=$A4)*('02_BillList'!$J$1:$J$4000=S$1),0),22)}
```

Comment: What do you think, if it would be simply possible achieving the same using a default formula rather than an array formula, why should one then use an array formula? Avoiding an array formula will either needs helper columns or restructuring the data. But to tell how, we first need to know the data structure `'02_BillList'!$B$1:$W$4000` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a helper column the array formula could be avoided:

We are using `'02_BillList'` column `X` as helper column.

In `'02_BillList'!$X$1:$X$4000` put the formula:

`=$B1&$J1`

Then use the formula:

```
=INDEX('02_BillList'!$B$1:$W$4000,MATCH($A4&S$1,'02_BillList'!$X$1:$X$4000,0),22)
```

Comment: I knew that but i dont wanna create any new column in the sheet. Though atlast i need to try like that. Is there any other option >> @axel Richter...Bdw thank you very much for your reply and i close by keeping ur answer only...